# Angular newbie: trying to use ng-change, getting "Module 'ngModel' is not available"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am brand new to Angular, and have read through all the tutorials, but am at the steep point of the learning curve where I'm building a real application for the first time.

I want to show a div only if a particular radio button is clicked.

This is my code:

```
// HTML file
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="ast-adh-p1-radio" ng-model="value" ng-change='answerP1(value)' value="yes"> Yes
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="ast-adh-p1-radio" ng-model="value" ng-change='answerP1(value)' value="no"> No
</label>
 <div ng-show="showQ1A">hello world </div>

// Controller file
 angular
   .module('adh.controllers', ['ngModel'])
  .controller('adhCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.answerP1 = function(value) {
      console.log('clicked radio button', value);
      // change $scope.showQ1A accordingly
    }
}]);
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error, and can't solve it by Googling:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module adh.controllers 
due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngModel due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngModel' is not available! You either misspelled 
the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you 
specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Do I need to load an external file in order to use `ngModel`? I can't see this [mentioned in the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController).

If so, is there a simpler way to do things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no module called `ngModel`, remove that dependency

```
 angular
   .module('adh.controllers',[])
  .controller('adhCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.answerP1 = function(value) {
      console.log('clicked radio button', value);
      // change $scope.showQ1A accordingly
    }
}]);
```

`ngModel` is a directive.